# Installing Levitron Digital Dimmer with Matching Remote

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I have a Levitron Digital Dimmer (DDL06-1LZ) and matching remote (DD00R-DLZ). Dimmer is at bottom of the stairs and the remote at the top.  Wire it all according to the diagram and dimmer doesn't function, and remote has not LED lights lit.  The instructions with the DDL06 says no neutral is required. A neutral is required with the DD00R.  I;m assuming, and this is my question, if I use the neutral for the DD00R (in this three way setup) then I need the neutral for the DDL06 (to complete the circuit), correct?  Thanks in advance...

BTW... there is very little on the Internet about the DDL06.  So, I'm assuming it's a fairly new dimmer. Does anyone know what dimmer this is a replacement for, if any?

Comment: The problem is, it is very hard to wire it as instructed, because every 3-way circuit is different and it's hard to write instructions for them all, and even more than that, color usage is completely arbitrary in 3-way circuits.   This for sure: there'll be no earthly way to help you without photos or accurate diagrams of what is in the boxes: both switches and possibly the lamp box too.  Ideally those pix are with the original 3-way switches back in and working in all respects, so we can identify which 2 are travelers.

Comment: I understand.  But I do have the hots and travelers identified.  I added a neutral to the DD00R.  I'm assuming is I have a neutral on the remote that I would need one on the dimmer... otherwise there would not be a circuit.  Correct?